# Using storyboard references with UINavigationController

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uistoryboard, storyboard-reference

I have the following hierarchy in my app: `UITabBarController` to many `UINavigationController`s. Each navigation controller has a `UIViewController`.

I’ve split this up so that each `UITabBarController`’s child view controller is linked via a storyboard reference. In each of these references there’s a `UINavigationController` as the initial view controller.

Again some of these other storyboard references are split up too, where one of the `UINavigationController`’s child view controllers also uses a storyboard reference.

These `UINavigationController`’s child view controllers in the new storyboards do not carry across the `UINavigationController` style. Unlike the `UITabBarController` which does take across the `UITabBarItem` and shows them in the `UINavigationController`.

Is there anything I can do to see the navigation item of these `UINavigationController`s so I can add bar button items in IB?

Answer (score 1):

It's straight forward really; just go to `Editor` > `Embed In` > `Navigation Controller` and embed your `view controller` in a `UINavigationController`. You can then select the `UIBarButton` items under the Object Library in xCode, drag and drop them to the navigation bar on your `View Controller` and voila!

You can then delete the `UINavigationController` when done with adding the `UIBarButton` items to your `VC`; those bar button items will still be referenced and shown in the final product when you run it.

Comment: Interesting answer and it works. Though it might lead to confusion for other people who see the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

In Storyboard go to the Attributes Inspector for the Controller you wish to add the navigation bar and click on top bar drop down instead of it saying 'inferred' click on 'Translucent Navigation Bar'

Comment: Hi, I tried this but it doesn’t allow me to add bar button items to the bar

Comment: Oh you need to go to the object library and add the navigation title and drag it onto your navigation bar then you can add bar button items.